# The property selected is not been set within my select object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of my dropdown with jQuery. I use the following code:

```
<select id="id145" name="id145" class="dropdown" >
    <option selected="selected" value="0">1 - test</option>
    <option value="1">2 - test</option>
</select>
```

with the following JS:

```
$('[name=id145] option').filter(function() { 
    return ($(this).val() == '1');
}).prop('selected', true);
```

I see that within my dropdown the value 1 (2 - test) is selected but whenever I look at the source code, by using the inspector tools, I still see this:

```
<option selected="selected" value="0">1 - test</option>
<option value="1">2 - test</option>
```

What I expected to see, and does not happen, is this:

```
<option value="0">1 - test</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">2 - test</option>
```

Does anyone know why? and is this even possible?

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dvgeuzwz/1/)

Comment: Side note: You can set the value of the select **much** more simply by using `val` on the `select` element itself: `$('[name=id145]').val('1');`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Even with the developer tools of chrome or Firefox I still do not see the `selected=selected` property appear when using jQuery to select a specific value

Comment: Sorry about that, "look at the source" tricked me and I didn't remember you were looking at `selected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that even using a DOM inspector (e.g., right-click the select and choose "Inspect element") you're still seeing `selected="selected"` on the first option, not the second. (And I can confirm that; I do too.)

The `selected` attribute sets the *default state* of the `option`; it doesn't necessarily reflect its *current* state. From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-option-selected):

> The `selected` attribute is a boolean attribute. It represents the **default** selectedness of the element.

*(my emphasis)*

The element's `selected` **property** tells you its current state, not the attribute. It's like the `value` attribute on `input` elements (which also sets the *default* value, not the current value). If that `select` box were in a `form` and you called `reset` on the form, the first option would be selected again, because that's the default for the select box.

If you want to know whether an option is *currently* selected, that information isn't available at the attribute level. You have to inspect the property instead:

```js
$('[name=id145]').val('1');
$("[name=id145] option").each(function() {
  console.log("Option " + this.value + ": Selected? " + this.selected); // or $(this).prop("selected")
});
```

```html
<select id="id145" name="id145" class="dropdown" >
    <option selected="selected" value="0">1 - test</option>
    <option value="1">2 - test</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah that is true. It got me a bit confused. The selected value is the default state. That make sense. Thank you for your explanation.